# Dynamic text on vertical seek bar thumb

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

Is there a way to create the image below where the thumb text is updated based on the progress using the seek bar listener. Also having the image at the bottom to be attached to the seekbar so that it is in the same position on all devices.

I have tried creating a TextDrawable and set the thumb to it but when scrolled to the top or bottom it gets slightly cropped.

Also have played with creating a custom vertical seek bar and rotating the seekbar, both have problems with regards to the seek bar requiring the dimensions (width/height) being the same for it to look and work correctly.

[image: Final output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to use custom vertical seek bar see below link
[Custom Vertical Seek bar1](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-verticalseekbar) [Custom Vertical Seek bar2](https://github.com/hansvdam/android-verticalseekbar)

Next You need Custom View over thumb. so you need to draws some text on over thumb image. the thumb image is white rectangle image. draw text based on seek bar progress. (i.e : 3 miles, 5 miles etc.) Use below method onProgressChanged().

```
public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    paint.setTextSize(20); 

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

    return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
}
```

or

Use TextThumbSeekBar Lib modify based on your requirement.
[TextThumbSeekBar](https://gist.github.com/yqritc/7b5c786930dfb9b47e7a)

Comment: Is there a way to add an image to the base of the seek bar?

Comment: simply create Relative Layout as a parent. Inside Relative Layout add Vertical Seek bar height match parent then add Image view set  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"finally  you will get , what you need.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using a bitmap and just use a drawable instead?

Comment: if you use drawable how can you change the text(like 3,4,5 miles.).